# django call_command returns no module named new_text

Tags: django, django-commands

I have to create a django command which needs to call another django command, so I had to use call_command which seems to be cool and simple:

```
call_command('command_to_call', new_text='arghslkjt')
```

The command command_to_call is supposed to store new_text content into the database. However, it returns

```
.......
call_command('command_to_call', new_text='arghslkjt')
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

make_option('-n','--new_text',
   type='string',
   dest='new_text',
   help='specify the new text title'),
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it the actual code which is throwing syntax error? I don't see any syntax error here `call_command('command_to_call', new_text='arghslkjt')`

Comment: Fixed now, no actually it's not the actual code, I was using import in place of new_text, and because import is a keyword, it didn't work. Sorry for the "typo" and thanks anyway :)